# Как решить задачу на приватный модификатор доступа в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Уже достаточно долго сижу над задачей и не впервые сталкиваюсь с непониманием последних 2 пунктов.

1. Сделайте у класса из предыдущего упражнения закрытыми все его поля.
2. Добавьте методы get и set для всех полей. Поскольку полей всего 4, то должно быть 4 метода get и 4 метода set.
3. Убедитесь, что доступа к полям уже нет за пределами класса.
4. Проверьте работу методов get и set.
5. Сделайте закрытый метод printlog(), в котором с помощью функции print() выводите значение переданного параметра.
6. В методах get и set вызывайте метод printlog с параметром: «Запрошено свойство NAME» (для методов get) или «Изменено свойство NAME» (для методов set). Вместо NAME должно быть подставлено имя соответствующего свойства.

Поскольку мне требуется 5 и 6 пункты, а в начале указано другое упражнение, прикреплю и свой код без последних двух пунктов.

```
class Pryg:
    __lehi = [0, 0]
    __shir = 0
    __dlin = 0
    def __init__(self, lehi, shir, dlin):
        self.__lehi = lehi
        self.__shir = shir
        self.__dlin = dlin
        self.__printlog()
    def getLEHI(self):
        return self.__lehi
    def getSHIR(self):
        return self.__shir
    def getDLIN(self):
        return self.__dlin
    def setLEHI(self, lehi):
        self.__lehi = lehi
    def setSHIR(self, shir):
        self.__lehi = shir
    def setDLIN(self, dlin):
        self.__lehi = dlin
    def __str__(self):
        return "Прямоугольник с координатами (" + str(self.lehi[0]) + ";" + str(self.lehi[1]) + ") шириной " + str(self.shir) + "и высотой " + str(self.dlin)
    def S(self):
        return self.shir * self.dlin
    def P(self):
        return (self.shir + self.dlin) * 2
p1 = Pryg([10, 20], 15, 10)
#p1.=__lehi #Не работает
#p1.__shir #Не работает
#p1.__dlin #Не работает
print(p1.getLEHI())
print(p1.getSHIR())
print(p1.getDLIN())
p1.setLEHI([11, 21])
p1.setSHIR(16)
p1.setDLIN(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, тут и написано, что нужно решать в лоб:

> В методах get и set вызывайте метод printlog с параметром: «Запрошено
> свойство NAME» (для методов get) или «Изменено свойство NAME» (для
> методов set). Вместо NAME должно быть подставлено имя соответствующего
> свойства.

Пример:

```
class Pryg:
    __lehi = [0, 0]
    __shir = 0
    __dlin = 0

    def __init__(self, lehi, shir, dlin):
        self.__lehi = lehi
        self.__shir = shir
        self.__dlin = dlin

    def __printlog(self, is_setter: bool, name: str):
        print(f'{"Изменено" if is_setter else "Запрошено"} свойство {name}')

    def getLEHI(self):
        self.__printlog(False, 'lehi')
        return self.__lehi

    def getSHIR(self):
        self.__printlog(False, 'shir')
        return self.__shir

    def getDLIN(self):
        self.__printlog(False, 'dlin')
        return self.__dlin

    def setLEHI(self, lehi):
        self.__printlog(True, 'lehi')
        self.__lehi = lehi

    def setSHIR(self, shir):
        self.__printlog(True, 'shir')
        self.__lehi = shir

    def setDLIN(self, dlin):
        self.__printlog(True, 'dlin')
        self.__lehi = dlin
```

Результат:

```
Запрошено свойство lehi
[10, 20]
Запрошено свойство shir
15
Запрошено свойство dlin
10
Изменено свойство lehi
Изменено свойство shir
Изменено свойство dlin
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Помимо ручного вызова метода с передачей параметров, можно было бы сделать более общее решение - через декораторы

Тут декоратор добавляется к каждому методу get/set и в зависимости от имени функции, будет выводиться информация (кст, если выводить `args` и `kwargs`, то можно показывать, что в функции передается)

Пример:

```
import functools


class Pryg:
    __lehi = [0, 0]
    __shir = 0
    __dlin = 0

    def __init__(self, lehi, shir, dlin):
        self.__lehi = lehi
        self.__shir = shir
        self.__dlin = dlin

    @staticmethod
    def __printlog(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            func_name = func.__name__
            is_setter = func_name.startswith('set')
            prop_name = func_name[3:].lower()
            print(f'{"Изменено" if is_setter else "Запрошено"} свойство {prop_name}')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    @__printlog
    def getLEHI(self):
        return self.__lehi

    @__printlog
    def getSHIR(self):
        return self.__shir

    @__printlog
    def getDLIN(self):
        return self.__dlin

    @__printlog
    def setLEHI(self, lehi):
        self.__lehi = lehi

    @__printlog
    def setSHIR(self, shir):
        self.__lehi = shir

    @__printlog
    def setDLIN(self, dlin):
        self.__lehi = dlin
```

Результат:

```
Запрошено свойство lehi
[10, 20]
Запрошено свойство shir
15
Запрошено свойство dlin
10
Изменено свойство lehi
Изменено свойство shir
Изменено свойство dlin
```

Answer (score 1):

5. По сути закрытый метод — это такой же метод с таким же правилами (см. геттеры и сеттеры в Вашем примере), но закрытый он из-за двух нижних подчёркиваний (как и для приватных полей класса).
6. Вызывайте данный метод точно так же, как Вы вызывали закрытые переменные: `self.__printlog()`, — только не забывайте подставлять в аргументы требуемые строки.